# Error hosting ASP.NET Core 3.1 project on IIS

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, iis

My ASP.NET Core 3.1 app can't be hosted on IIS; once the login page is loaded, I get this error:

[image: An unhandled win32 exception occurred in w3wp.exe]

and when I try to log in, I am getting a "page not found" error:

> This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:801/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F
> HTTP ERROR 404

In the event viewer, I see this error:

[image: Error in the Event Viewer1]

[image: Error in the Event Viewer2]

[image: Error in the Event Viewer3]

My connection

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection":"Server=DESKTOP-HKHGAFC;Database=Ticket02Testv2;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

My IIS settings:

[IIS Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pSvX.png)

My folder access security:

[Folder Access Seucirty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zxFK.png)

FYI: From the debugger its working ok and the DB is seeded as expected

Comment: Can you host an empty project (created directly from `dotnet new mvc`) on this IIS machine? That test can rule out quite a few common causes for you and reveal the culprit.

Comment: @LexLi
I used the ASP Core Template, and hosted it in the IIS, from the Visual studio it's working as expected( i can log in and register )  but from the IIS showing error.
FYI: **I Can Navigate into the pages which don't have any connection with the DB** 
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: |4f82847c-4461e4b0c2d2d22b.
Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to publish an ASP.NET Core app to IIS, you need to install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle.

Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle on the IIS server. The bundle installs the .NET Core Runtime, .NET Core Library, and the ASP.NET Core Module. The module allows ASP.NET Core apps to run behind IIS.

Download the installer using the following link:

1. [Current .NET Core Hosting Bundle installer (direct download)](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-5.0.2-windows-hosting-bundle-installer).
2. Restart the server or execute net stop was /y followed by net start w3svc in a command shell.

I suggest that you first publish a template Asp.net core project to determine whether it is a project or an IIS issue.

Comment: I made sure to instal the Bundle Installer from the first place, it's already in the IIS settings,
I have created **template Asp.net core** And hosted it in the IIS, I can only navigate to the pages which not connected with the DB, but with the pages which have a module I am getting an error 
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: |d88016c0-483366b9763ba7dc.
FYI: I can see that  **AspNetCoreModuleV2** Already installed in the Site Module